# find path to file in parallel directory based on location of bash script

Tags: bash, path

I want to run a bash script that invokes a dataset in a parallel directory as a variable. I must use a relative path to this file. So far I have been able to retrieve the full path of the script using the SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/get-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within-the-script-itself). How can I modify this path to change it to the path of target file in the parallel directory? Alternatively, is there a superior way to obtain this resource based only on the location of the script?

script pseudo path = "project/scripts/myscript.sh"

data pseduo path = "project/data/mydata.csv"

contents of myscript.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash
parent_path=$( cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" ; pwd -P )

echo "$parent_path"
```

How can I alter `$parent_path` to get the path to my data?

Comment: `$(dirname $0)/../data/mydata.csv`

Comment: Thanks @WilliamPursell. This works for me.